# Where are double double quotes coming from?

Tags: angularjs

This is in my allowed_times:

[Tue Dec 30 2014 06:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET), Tue Dec 30 2014 06:15:00 GMT+0100 (CET), Tue Dec 30 2014 06:30:00 GMT+0100 (CET), Tue Dec 30 2014 06:45:00 GMT+0100 (CET), Tue Dec 30 2014 07:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET), Tue Dec 30 2014 07:15:00 GMT+0100 (CET), Tue Dec 30 2014 07:30:00 GMT+0100 (CET), Tue Dec 30 2014 07:45:00 GMT+0100 (CET), Tue Dec 30 2014 08:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET), Tue Dec 30 2014 08:15:00 GMT+0100 (CET), Tue Dec 30 2014 08:30:00 GMT+0100 (CET), Tue Dec 30 2014 08:45:00 GMT+0100 (CET), Tue Dec 30 2014 09:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET), Tue Dec 30 2014 09:15:00 GMT+0100 (CET), Tue Dec 30 2014 09:30:00 GMT+0100 (CET), Tue Dec 30 2014 09:45:00 GMT+0100 (CET), Tue Dec 30 2014 10:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET), Tue Dec 30 2014 10:15:00 GMT+0100 (CET)]

I have this in my template:

```
<select ng-model="timesheet.start">
  <option ng-repeat="period in allowed_times" value={{period}}>{{ period | date:'H:mm' }}</option>
</select>
```

And this is set in the service:

```
  Object.defineProperty(Timesheet.prototype, 'start', {
    get: function() {
      if (_start == undefined){
        _start = new Date(moment(this.time_start));
      }
      return _start;
    },
    set: function(value) {
      if (moment(value).isValid()) {
        _start = moment(moment(_currentDate) + moment.duration(value));
        this.time_start = _start;
      }
    }
  });
```

I have set a breakpoint on the first line of the setter function.  When I alter the value in the select, I see this value coming in:

```
""2014-12-30T07:30:00.889Z""
```

Where are all the double quotes coming from?  The hour and minutes are displayed correctly in the select box so I assume it recognizes the values as a correct string.

Comment: not recommended to use `ng-repeat` for `<option>`, use `ng-options` instead on select tag

Comment: also would probably help to use quotes for value attribute

Answer (score 0):

Changing the code into this as charlietfl suggested got it working:

```
      <select ng-model="timesheet.start" ng-options="(period | date:'H:mm') for period in allowed_times track by period">
      </select>
```